# Fact table which can be split by multiple different dimensions but not simultaneously - How to model?

Tags: ssas, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

We're looking at integrating a new data set into our existing data warehouse and cube solution. The dimensionality of this data set is to be Date, Hour and Device Name. Due to limitations with the source data, we are able to pull data extracts segmented by Date and Hour *or* Date and Device.

In other words, the data can split by Hour and Device but not both at the same time.

Within our team we are in confusion as to how to model this. One approach raised was to have two separate fact tables with the following columns:

**FactMyData_Hour:** DateID, Hour, *(Metrics)*

**FactMyData_Device:** DateID, Device, *(Metrics)*

The problem I have with this approach is 1) Lack of intuitiveness to an end user and 2) It's not extensible, for example if we wanted to pull in other segments at a later stage, it would necessitate yet another Fact Table.

Ideally, we want the user to be able to choose a segment (Device or Hour) without a reliance on choosing a specific fact table. (Users will be using Excel to explore the cube). We're unsure on how to model based on this requirement - Any insight that could be offered would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: How do you get the source data? Is there no way to get it at the most detailed level? You say that you consider adding other segments in the future... So maybe it's possible to get date-hour-device grain... I am afraid that any other approach would be a pseudo solution... If you really can't change the source, keep your two fact tables and then create a view as a union with Date, Type (Hour or Device), Type_Value (1, 2, 3... Desktop, Mobile...), Metrics. In Excel force to choose one type (i.e. by radio button). Then user can retrieve data without choosing different fact tables.

Comment: Pivoted fact table ? Data in rows & Device, Hour in columns. One view at a glance ... would this approach be possible here ?? Sample data required to understand question thoroughly ...